# Any way to publish artifact from local maven repo to Nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus

I use a kind of continous delivery pipeline. Each CI build gets a unique version (no snapshots) and is installed to local maven repo on CI server. There are few buids daily like 2.1.0-231. Then it goes to QA and UAT. 
Once a specific version gets approval on UAT i want to publish this specific version to a central Nexus **without rebuild**.

I know I can do some combination of deploy-file but maybe there is an easier way to do this out of the box?

I don't want to push every build to nexus as a released version. My local CI repo i kind of a staging repo and gests cleaned up automatically.

Comment: Which version of Nexus do you use?

Answer (score 3):

Rich Seddon & Dan Rollo created good posts about different ways to upload files to Nexus. These guys seem to be from the company Sonatype which created and owns Nexus, so the information should be accurate.

- **Nexus 2**: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-2-
- **Nexus 3:** https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006744008